# Is there any way to set tabIndex of Image elements in WPF by the C# code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf

We can certainly set an Image to be tab focusable. How can we set the TabIndex of that Image to modify the order at which the Tab key lands on that image?

PS. I would like to do it by the C# code behind, not by xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you have an image:

```
<Image Name="img" Source="images/pineapple.jpg" />
```

then it is possible to set by code behind:

```
KeyboardNavigation.SetTabIndex(img, 5);
```

and by xaml:

```
<Image Name="img" Source="images/pineapple.jpg" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"/>
```